# Power app to track other apps usage by users as well as productivity of the app

Tags: powerapps

Please assist with a power app to be build

I have a the below use case and not sure how to do it;

Currently once a solution is deployed the solution is not monitored effectively in terms of its productivity and or performance. Further once a solution is deployed there are no effective means of communication for teams to report and track whether their solution is live or has a down time.

Im new to power apps and was not sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

Good news, having analytics about apps is so important that Microsoft provides several pre-built tools for this purpose. Check these out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/analytics-powerapps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/coe/power-bi-monitor

They might not cover all of the aspects you need, but it's easier to customize them than building a new app from scratch.